# I want an another image than the one is the cover image product

Tags: prestashop, smarty

i have a issue with a prestahop module, it's Advanced Top Menu.
I a have a submenu with my products and it show the image cover of the product. But, i want to show a another image which is a second image of the product not the cover image.

I sought where can i do that and I find the file here : /themes/at_manor/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl

A part of the file product.tpl

```
<a href="{$product.url}" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">
                    <img
                        class="img-fluid"
                        src = " 
 {$product.cover.bySize.large_default.url}"
                        alt = "{if 
!empty($product.cover.legend)}{$product.cover.legend}{else} 
 {$product.name|truncate:30:'...'}{/if}"
                        data-full-size-image- 
 url = "{$product.cover.large.url}"
                    >  
                    {if isset($cfg_product_one_img) 
&& $cfg_product_one_img}
                        <span class="product- 
 additional" data-idproduct="{$product.id_product}"></span>
                    {/if}
                </a>
```